# Desagrupar datos generando una lista de fechas por mes

Tags: excel, powerquery

Considerando un set de datos almacenado con su fecha inicio y fecha fin, y cosiderando que los bienes se venden mensualmente a cada cliente en una cantidad fija y constante. Quisiera transformar la siguiente tabla a un total por mes

[image: Datos]

Resultado Esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sería lo mejor lograrlo utilizando PowerQuery.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generamos una nueva columna con una **lista** de los meses (lista es similar a un array), todos dentro de la misma celda. Usamos [List.Generate( inicial, condición, incremento)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) para obtener la lista de meses a partir de la fecha de inicio y fin (es similar a un `while`).
2. Expandimos para que cada elemento de la lista vaya a una fila diferente

**Código**:

```
let
    //Replicar tu ejemplo manualmente
    Origen = #table({"Cliente", "fecha inicio", "fecha fin", "ventas por mes"}, {{"A",#date(2020,1,1),#date(2020,2,1),10}, {"B",#date(2020,1,1),#date(2020,4,1),5}}),
    
    //Generar la lista de meses en columna nueva
    ListaMeses = Table.AddColumn(Origen, "fecha", each List.Generate( ()=>[fecha inicio], (actual)=> actual <= [fecha fin], (actual)=> Date.AddMonths(actual, 1)), type list),
    
    //Llevar a filas
    Expandir = Table.ExpandListColumn(ListaMeses, "fecha"),

    //Seleccionar las columnas que te interese
    SelCols = Table.SelectColumns(Expandir,{"Cliente", "fecha", "ventas por mes"})
in
    SelCols
```

La parte importante del código es:

```
List.Generate( 
    ()=>[fecha inicio], //desde esta fecha
    (actual)=> actual <= [fecha fin], //siempre que esté en el rango
    (actual)=> Date.AddMonths(actual, 1) //sumarle 1 mes
)
```

que genera una lista desde la `[fecha inicio]`, mientras cada elemento generado sea `<= [fecha fin]`, incrementando de a 1 mes con `Date.AddMonths(actual, 1)`.

---

**Capturas del paso a paso**:

- Original [image: Original]
- Lista de meses en cada celda [image: ListaMeses]
- Expandir [image: Expandir]
- Sólo las columnas que interesan [image: cols]